# Get taxonomy from one loop and use it in another

Tags: php, wordpress

This code in the first loop:

```
 <?php
    $terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'produktkategori', '', ', ', '' ) ;
    echo strip_tags($terms_as_text);
    ?>
```

Results in "Spanskt". I want "Spanskt" to be entered in the second loop where it says "Spanskt". Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

```
// First loop
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php
$terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'produktkategori', '', ', ', '' ) ;
echo strip_tags($terms_as_text);
?> // The value of this...</h1> 

    <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">    
        Some content
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

// Second loop  
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'bocker', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'produktkategori' => 'Spanskt // ...should be entered here', 'orderby' => 'rand', ) ); ?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        Some content

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
// First loop
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'forfattare', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>


<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


    <?php $string = get_the_title() ;
    $forfattare = createAlias( $string ); 
    ?>

         // Second loop 
         <?php $loop_2 = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'bocker', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'forfattare' => ''.$forfattare.'', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'order' => 'ASC', ) ); ?>

         <?php while ( $loop_2->have_posts() ) : $loop_2->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="italic"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>

         <?php endwhile; ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```